# What does ExtJS ComboBox triggerAction: "all" really do?

Tags: javascript, combobox, extjs

I tried to create a simple ComboBox:

```
var combo1 = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
  store: [1,2,3],
  renderTo: document.body
});
```

But written this way it acts strangely:

- When you first time pop open the dropdown, it offers three choices.
- You choose one.
- But when you after that try to change your selection, the dropdown only offers one choice - the one you previously selected.

I compared my code to the [samples](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/combos.html) on Ext homepage and discovered that adding `triggerAction: "all"` solves my problem:

```
var combo2 = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
  triggerAction: "all",
  store: [1,2,3],
  renderTo: document.body
});
```

ExtJS documentation for `triggerAction` doesn't tell me a lot:

> The action to execute when the trigger is clicked.
>   Use 'all' to run the query specified by the allQuery
>   config option (defaults to 'query')

I haven't specified the allQuery option. Actually, I don't want to perform a query to the server at all.

So what does this `triggerAction` really do?

And is setting it to `"all"` really what I should do when I just want a simple static combobox?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After choosing an item, the list is filtered to match the current text value.  In your case, it's always exactly the chosen value, but is more obvious with multi-character values (see the state names example in Ext).  If you delete the selected value, the dropdown will go back to having all values.  `triggerAction:'all'` means do not filter, always show all values.

Comment: This makes sense now, but this is a really poorly-named option!

Comment: The reason for the name is that the config is inherited from `TriggerField` and so is used more generically outside of combos and does not even have to relate to filtering in other implementations. But yes, a combo-specific alias that is more descriptive might be nice.